# Tool bar invade layout

Tags: android, toolbar

Tengo un **Toolbar** hijo que cree en el **MainActivity**, pero en otras pantallas(Fragments) se muestra arriba de estas, y ocultando algunos elementos, quisiera saber como solucionar esto.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            style="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La mayoría de las ocasiones, nuestra aplicación no necesitará dibujar debajo de la barra de estado o la barra de navegación, pero como en tu caso, se debe asegurar que los elementos no estén ocultos debajo. Esto se puede lograr usando el atributo en tu `Toolbar`:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows = "true"
```

Este atributo establece un "padding" de la vista que se muestra debajo para poder garantizar que los elementos contenidos no se superpongan a las ventanas del sistema.

---

También puedes agregar un "padding" a tu toolbar definiendo la medida del actionbar:

```
  android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```